# Requests on IIS logs for each day

Tags: sql-server, iis, logging, logparser

I have to find informations in IIS logs.
I use the software called 'Log Parser Studio'

I need the top 10 of the slowest pages for each day included in the logs.

Here is the request written to get the top 25 slowest pages for all datas (all days included) :

```
SELECT TOP 25  
    cs-uri-stem as URL,  
    MAX(time-taken) As Max,  
    MIN(time-taken) As Min,  
    Avg(time-taken) As Average  
    FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'  
GROUP BY URL  
ORDER By Average DESC
```

I don't know how to get informations for each day in 1 request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 25  
    cs-uri-stem as URL,
    date as Date,  
    MAX(time-taken) As Max,  
    MIN(time-taken) As Min,  
    Avg(time-taken) As Average  
    FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'  
GROUP BY URL, Date  
ORDER By Date, Average DESC
```